# Google Cloud Run: occasional connection issues while querying postgres and redis

Tags: google-cloud-run

We recently moved a couple of Java servers from Heroku to Cloud Run. Fairly regularly (multiple times per day) requests are failing because a database query on our Postgres server could not be executed:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```

At almost exactly the same time, requests to our Redis server fail as well:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The Postgres and Redis servers run on Google Cloud, in the same region as the web servers (hosted by Aiven).

We're using Hikari as connection pool for Postgres, and Jedis for Redis.

I set the max lifetime of connections in the Hikari pool to 30s, since I assumed Cloud Run was killing long-running connections. But that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Has anyone seen this? And is there a solution?

Google seems to have some docs that describe this issue, but they don't contain a solution as far as I can tell: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#connection-reset-by-peer